# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, entity-framework

I got an issue trying to set up OWIN identity and have installed the entity **Framework 6.1.2** libraries and i'am using mysql for backend. But when I run the application and try and get this to for example register a user I get the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute' from
>   assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`6.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModelBuilder()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) at
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include[T](IQueryable`1 source,
>   String path) at
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include[T,TProperty](IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 path) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.GetUserAggregateAsync(Expression`1
>   filter) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.FindByNameAsync(String
>   userName) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.FindByNameAsync(String
>   userName) at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator`2.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator`2.d__0.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.d__0.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.d__d.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1
>   func) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.Create[TUser,TKey](UserManager`2
>   manager, TUser user, String password) at
>   Account_register.btnRegister_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\ashish\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\WebSites\online\Account\register.aspx.cs:line 37

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this might be related to your issue, but my MySql OWIN Identity project fails under EF 6.1.2.  I backed off to 6.1.1 and it works fine.

I already had the project complete and running when I went to EF 6.1.2, so I noticed the issue in my unit tests, that started spitting out.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException:  An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition.  See the inner
>   exception for details. --->
>
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near  'FROM ((SELECT CASE WHEN
>   (`Extent2`.`UserId` IS  NULL) THEN (NULL)  ELSE (1) END' at line 29.